# How to load OSM (GeoJSON) data to ArangoDB?

Tags: json, openstreetmap, geojson, arangodb

How I can load OSM data to ArangoDB?

I loaded data sed named `luxembourg-latest.osm.pbf` from OSM, than converted it to JSON with [OSMTOGEOJSON](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson/), after I tried to load result geojson to ArangoDB with next command: `arangoimp --file out.json --collection lux1 --server.database geodb` and got hude list of errors:

```
...
2017-03-17T12:44:28Z [7712] WARNING at position 719386: invalid JSON type (expecting object, probably parse error), offending context: ],
2017-03-17T12:44:28Z [7712] WARNING at position 719387: invalid JSON type (expecting object, probably parse error), offending context: [
2017-03-17T12:44:28Z [7712] WARNING at position 719388: invalid JSON type (expecting object, probably parse error), offending context: 5.867441,
...
```

What I am doing wrong?

upd: it's seems that converter osm2json converter should be run with option `osmtogeojson --ndjson` that produce items not as single Json, but in line by line mode.

Comment: What does the import file look like in lines 719384 to 719390? Is it valid JSON there?

Comment: Yes, it's right JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As @dmitry-bubnenkov already found out, `--ndjson` is required to produce the right input for ArangoImp.

One has to know here, that ArangoImp expects a JSON-Subset (since it doesn't parse the json on its own) dubbed as `JSONL`. 
Thus, Each line of the JSON-File is expected to become one json document in the collection after the import. To maximize performance and simplify the implementation, The json is not completely parsed before sending it to the server.

It tries to chop the JSON into chunks with the maximum request size that the server permits. It leans on the JSONL-line endings to isolate possible chunks.

However, the server expects valid JSON for sure. Sending the chopped part to the server with possibly incomplete JSON documents will lead to parse errors on the server, which is the error message you saw in your output.